# Position fixed not working properly in IE when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using [KoGrid](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid) to display my records. I have made header as fixed, which means when we do browser scroll down the header should become sticky at the top, so I am doing it using jQuery. Below is the code:

```
var distance = $('.kgTopPanel').offset(),
    $window = $(window),
    topDistance = null;

if (distance) {
    topDistance = distance.top;
}

$window.on('scroll', function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= topDistance) {
        $('.kgTopPanel').css('top', '0');
        $('.kgTopPanel').css('position', 'fixed');
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    } else {
        $('.kgTopPanel').css('top', '');
        $('.kgTopPanel').css('position', 'relative');
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
});
```

It's working fine in Chrome and FireFox. However, when I use Internet Explorer, then the behavior is little weird. I can see the lag in the rendering of the DOM. For example, when you scroll up then header move to the top of the screen (covering the menus) and after some time(microseconds) it comes back to proper position. This lag is visible while scrolling.

Thanks